# Convert IntStream to Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an `IntStream` and want for each element of that stream to do some calculations and return them as `Map` where keys are int values and values are result of that computations. I wrote following piece of code:

```java
IntStream.range(0,10)
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> computeSmth(i)));
```

where `computeSmth(Integer a)`. I got next compiler error

```
method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
 required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
 found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.String>>
 reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `IntStream` only has the 3-argument `collect`.  You should either rewrite your `toMap` in 3-arument form or convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` with `.boxed()`

Comment: @Misha Thanks, I just learnt about `boxed()`. It's an improvement over `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`, for sure. :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is my code, it will work for you.

**Function Reference version**

```
public class AppLauncher {

public static void main(String a[]){
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = IntStream.range(1,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),AppLauncher::computeSmth));
    System.out.println(map);
}
  public static Integer computeSmth(Integer i){
    return i*i;
  }
}
```

**Lambda expression version**

```
public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = IntStream.range(1,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),i->i*i));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed, `.boxed()` was the key to success !